# How to add payment card programmatically into apple wallet

Tags: ios, applepay

We tried to add credit, debit card details into Apple Pay from within our app.

The below are the things from apple doc.

Important Adding payment passes requires a special entitlement issued by Apple. Your app must include this entitlement before this class can be instantiated. For more information on requesting this entitlement, see the Card Issuers section at developer.apple.com/apple-pay/.
In sandbox environment we tried entitlement key , but we can't load payment card details.

We can add payment card iTunes manually. But can possible to add payment card in apple pay wallet programmatically.

Is't possible to mock the Testcard (payment card) like pkpass file?
No documentation available to mock the payment card in sandbox environment.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/passkit/pkaddpaymentpassviewcontroller?language=objc

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is an amazing step-by-step document on how you can add card to Apple Wallet. https://medium.com/p/eae2458617bc

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have the entitlement key in place (and I assume you have acquired the special permission from Apple). I am also assuming that you are using the `PKAddPaymentPassViewController` for the provisioning process. If all of this is correct then there are a few more things you need to keep in mind. First of all, you cannot test this using mock data or even test environments. You must use production data with real payment cards which can be confirmed by Apple Pay with the card issuer. Also, the app must be distributed with TestFlight in order for it to work, so you cannot run from Xcode directly.

Comment: What should be implementaion for method addPaymentPassViewController:generateRequestWithCertificateChain:nonce:nonceSignature:completionHandler:

Comment: In this delegate method you should take the certificates, nonce and nonceSignature provided by the method and probably pass it to your backend. Your backend will then take this data and send it to the card company (for instance Visa) and return data that enables you to construct a `PKAddPaymentPassRequest` which you will pass to the completionHandler of this method. This is all described in the document Apple provides when you get the special permission to use the credit card provisioning entitlement.

Comment: Thanks pajevic. Yes I read it in the documentation. I am looking for a swift code for delegate methods as I am not actually able to map into code.

Comment: @GauravBorole can I ask you to link official apple documentation related to add Payment Pass implementation

Comment: @msamardzic It is not publicly available AFAIK. It is only provided by Apple to organisations that get approved for payment pass provisioning (usually banks and card issuers) and it is covered by an NDA. So you need to contact apple to get approved (if you qualify) and then they will send you the documentation.

Comment: @pajevic thnx a lot man. 
I run successfully PKAddPaymentPassViewController passing some data as cardholder name and last 4 digits but didn't find any doc whats next steps (eg addPaymentPassViewController(...) )

Answer (score 0):

> **Enabling In-App Provisioning of Payment Cards**
>
> Use this entitlement to enable the in-app provisioning of payment
> cards. This entitlement allows you to initialize and present a `PKAddPaymentPassViewController` object.
>
> In the entitlement’s file, add the `com.apple.developer.payment-pass-provisioning` key with a Boolean value of `YES`. You need special permission from Apple to submit apps with this key enabled. For more information, contact apple-pay-inquiries@apple.com.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/ApplePayandPassKitEntitlements/ApplePayandPassKitEntitlements.html

Comment: In your experience how long does it take to get the entitlement or a response from Apple after you contact them at the apple-pay-inquiries email address?

Comment: @most200 It seems that you can hardly get the permission if your company is not financial related. I’ve send an email to contact with apple, but never get a reply. But you could still have a try.